# If $f(x) := h(g(x))$, what can we say about $f(x)$ when $h(g(x)+\varepsilon)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have a very banal question I realised I cannot answer (I am not even sure it makes sense at all). I am quite at loss when dealing with the algebra of functions.

Let $f, g, h$ be functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, such that $f(x) := h(g(x))$.

Does it make sense to ask what is equal $f(x)$ given $h(g(x)+\varepsilon)$?
Can we manipulate the expression further?

Thanks a lot for any feedback.

Answer (score 2):

If $\epsilon$ is small and h is differentiable, $h(g(x)+\epsilon)$~$ f(x) + \epsilon h'(g(x))$

Comment: this is true but the reader should be aware that this amounts to a linear extension of the function around the point $x$. If $h$ is "very" non linear then $\epsilon$ could need to be EXTREMELY small to get any amount of precision.  You can also extend this to quadratic, cubic etc. extensions by using more terms, much like a Taylor series.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I see what you mean but $f(x)$ is still $h(g(x))$,
it has no relation to $\epsilon$ whatsoever, i.e. it's not a function of the $\epsilon$.

Also $f(x+\epsilon) = h(g(x + \epsilon))$ so this $f(x+\epsilon)$ again cannot be
expressed as a function of $h(g(x) + \epsilon)$

In fact, I think $h(g(x) + \epsilon)$ may be not equal to $f(y)$ for any $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing can be said in general about the expression $h(g(x) + \epsilon)$ without further assumptions on the functions involved.

A basic example would be, if $h$ is a linear function then

$h(g(x)+\epsilon) = h(g(x))+h(\epsilon) = f(x) + h(\epsilon)$

In fact taking $h$ to be a polynomial would give you a lot of traction but none of it may be useful to you, it depends on what you are trying to find out